# LibGdx - Adding array of actors to a table, with delay

Tags: libgdx

I want to have several comets falling in the background of my UI,I have a working comet Actor that does what it is supposed to, but I am not sure how to create a continuous spawn with these comets (with a random delay between each) in a table, without scene2d/actors it would look something like:

```
cometTimer += delta
if(cometTimer >= interval){
    addCometToArray();
    cometTimer = 0;
}
```

With the cometArray being looped over and drawn every frame, and then removing the entity when it goes out of bounds.

The only way I know how to add Actors to a table is like this:

```
table().add(new DialogComet());
```

How would I go about adding this type of behaviour using Scene2d?

Comment: Table extends Group, which can give you the Actors in the table as pretty much an array (libGDX SnapshotArray). So you could use similar logic to your code anyway. Add the comet to the Table, use methods like drawChildren or getChildren if you want to loop over the comets (to see if they are out of bounds,set position, whatever) and then use tableVar.removeActor(specificComet) when OOB.

Comment: @PeterR I've been trying to implement this but cannot get it to work, any way you could write some example code in an answer?

Comment: I will try but may be a couple/few days before I can get to it.

Comment: pretty busy with work and travel these days, but I posted an answer. Could be way off base, but hopefully that was the direction you were asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for, but the below is a small working app that shows comets "falling" from the top to bottom, using Tables and having the tables manage the comets (no separate array/data structure). I created a small Comet class that extends Actor as well, to allow for movement and placement.

"main" class:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;

public class StageComet  implements ApplicationListener {

    private static final float INTERVAL = 0.3f;

    private Batch batch;
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private BitmapFont font;

    private Table rootTable;
    private Table cometTable;
    private Stage stage;
    private Iterator<Actor> iter;
    private Comet comet;

    private float cometTimer = 0;
    private float delta = 0;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 960, 640);

        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont();

        stage = new Stage();

        /*
         * The root table could contain main "play" actors. It is empty in this example.
         */
        rootTable = new Table();
        rootTable.setFillParent(true);

        /*
         * Usually in Scene2d I think the practice is only to have 1 root table that takes up the entire screen (above), 
         * but for simplicity/illustrative purposes, I created a cometTable only, set it to Fill Parent as well, and the
         * getChildren() of the table will have our array of comets in play at any given time.
         */
        cometTable = new Table();
        cometTable.setFillParent(true);

        stage.addActor(rootTable);
        stage.addActor(cometTable);
    }


    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        delta = Gdx.app.getGraphics().getDeltaTime();
        stage.act(delta);                                               // make sure the comets "fall"

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);                          // simple rendering of comets, they are just a circle ...
        iter = cometTable.getChildren().iterator();                     // Table subclasses Group, which has a snapshot array of its Actors 
        while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
            comet = (Comet)iter.next();

            shapeRenderer.circle(comet.getX(), comet.getY(), 20.0f);    // Draw the comet

            if ( comet.getY() < -100 ) {                                // Hack/hardcode, if the comet fell far enough "off stage" ...
                iter.remove();                                          // ... remove it from the stage
            }
        }
        shapeRenderer.end();

        /*
         * Sample code from original question on how to create a comet without scene2d ...
         */
        cometTimer += delta;
        if ( cometTimer > INTERVAL ) {
            cometTable.add(new Comet());                                // ... but in this case, we use scene2d
            cometTimer = 0;
        }

        /*
         * To keep track, display a simple message of # of comets on stage at any given time.
         */
        batch.begin();
        font.draw(batch, "Comets on stage: " + cometTable.getChildren().size, 100, 100);
        batch.end();
     }

    /*
     * I may have missed disposing something, but you get the idea ...
     */
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        shapeRenderer.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
        stage.dispose();
        font.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {  }

    @Override
    public void pause() { }

    @Override
    public void resume() { }
}
```

And the small Comet class:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;

public class Comet extends Actor{

    /*
     * Spawn a comet at the top of the screen, in the middle
     */
    public Comet() {
        super();
        this.setY(Gdx.app.getGraphics().getHeight());
        this.setX(Gdx.app.getGraphics().getWidth()/2.0f);
    }

    /*
     * Let the comet fall (same speed) to the bottom of the screen ...
     */
    @Override
    public void act (float delta) {
        this.setY(this.getY() - 10);
        super.act(delta);
    }

}
```

Comment: I find another way of solving my problem, but will accept and give bounty since this seems to be another working solution, thanks for your help!